# How to do Makefile Pattern Rules with List of Files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Wondering how to apply something such as [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) to accomplish the following in the Makefile:

```
FILES := a b c d

$(FILES).c:
  run build $(FILE).c
  # use $(FILE) without .c extension, etc.
```

Without having to name all of the values in `FILES` like `a.c`, `b.c`, etc. because I am going to use the names elsewhere.

If I try the above with `make a.c`, I get:

```
No rule to make target `a.c'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`addsuffix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) built-in function, which already operates on lists, could be useful here:

```
targets := $(addsuffix .c,$(FILES))
```

---

However, you could simply use pattern rules instead. The automatic variable `$*` would correspond to the *stem* (i.e., the `%` part):

```
%.c:
   run build $@
   # use $* for filename without .c extension, etc.
```

Comment: Does it work now? Or where those `.c` files phony targets? For phony targets you need static pattern rules instead.

Comment: @LancePollard Great!